# Fancybox show white instead of image

Tags: javascript, fancybox-2

I use fancybox for my website it worked fine but now only shows a white image

```
http://markazirey.com/gallery/gallery-kudak.html
```

I really have no idea what just happened!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see this in gallery.css:

```
div img {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

If I remove that the image appears. A remedy is to add this CSS to somewhere relevant:

```
.fancybox-image {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

I'm not sure why it broke in the first place.

Comment: thanks I needed that css protocol but I fixed that from your answer yyhanks a lot :)